# group 2 columns and based on the group value take the group based on specific value

Tags: python, pandas

My code:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
                    'group': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                    'check':[0.5, 0.5,0.5,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.2,0.2]})
```

output:

```
data.groupby(['group','check']).size()
group  check
1      0.3      1
       0.5      3
2      0.2      2
       0.3      2
dtype: int64
```

I wish to get

Since we have group '1' and '2'.

based on the above output, I wish to take only the second group or any group above 1(given if we have more than 2 groups).

example output:

```
group  check
2      0.2      2
       0.3      2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Are groups all numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following. So here, we are getting the individual `groups` and getting all the items where group key does not have 1 in the 0th element. Each key would be a tuple `(group_id, check_val)` and then concat them back and do a `groupby`.

```
grps = [grp for k, grp in data.groupby(['group','check']).groups.items() if k[0]!=1]
new_df =  pd.concat([data.loc[g] for g in grps]).groupby(['group', 'check']).size()
```

Which gives,

```
group  check
2      0.2      2
       0.3      2
dtype: int64
```

### Option 2:

```
new_df = data.loc[(data['group']!=1)].groupby(['group', 'check']).size()
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, this is really helpful. By the way, do you think is there any other way to apply it using pandas functions?

Comment: @Anonymous, so you mean doing this another way? Looking back at your question, can't you just remove all the elements with `group=1` and then perform groupby?